# In AppEngine (JDO), how can I query for an entity that requires sorting by a property that isn't part of the inequality filter?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sorting, filter, jdo

I'm having the same problem as mentioned here: [Appengine filter inequality and ordering fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671587/appengine-filter-inequality-and-ordering-fails) i.e. I want to sort by a property that isn't part of the filter. For e.g.

```
" select from " + Post.class.getName() + 
" where createdAt >= :yesterday && " + 
" createdAt <= :now " + 
" order by likes desc ");
```

How can I do this efficiently using GQL/JDO instead of doing it in-memory? Any suggestions? I can't do cron jobs or task queues since then I would have to run this cron job every second/millisecond since the "now" variable equals the current time. Any suggestions as to how I can do this? I still haven't used direct AppEngine code in  my application yet, so I can still switch to another platform. Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to get the posts for one or more days, ordered by likes, maybe you could have a field on each post which is the day (millisecond value rounded to the beginning of the day).  then maybe you could do something like (assuming likes is always >= 0):

```
"select from Post where likes >= 0 && (createdAtDay = :nowDay || createdAtDay = :yesterday) order by likes desc"
```